# Metric tensor for n-sphere in ambient coordinates

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let $S^n$ be the unit [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:

$$ S^n = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid a \cdot a = 1 \} $$

What is the induced metric tensor for the sphere, in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ coordinates?

$$ g(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_{n+1})$$

Note that

$$ \text{arclength}(a,b) = \arccos(a \cdot b) $$

How do I obtain the metric tensor components from this expression? Should I take $b=a+\delta a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induced metric is just the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, i.e. $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, but restricted to act on vectors tangent to $S^n$. You need to choose a system of $n$ coordinates parametrizing $S^n$ alone (or an $n$-frame tangent to $S^n$) if you want to get an $n \times n$ matrix of components for $g$.

Comment: Thank you. I am working with $(n+1)$ coordinates instead of $n$ to avoid the singularities present in hyper-spherical coordinates. Would it be fine to perform all calculations involving the metric tensor (e.g. Christoffel symbols, parallel transport, etc) using the $(n+1)$-dimensional metric tensor directly, or is there something else I should take into account?

Comment: @user1667423: if you want to work in ambient coordinates then you need to project vectors back on to the surface every time you take a covariant derivative. All the equations you usually find for parallel transport etc are for surface coordinates, not ambient ones; so you can't apply them. For example the equation for parallel transport of a vector $V$ will be $V'' - (V'' \cdot \vec{x}) \vec{x}=0$ rather than the $V'' = 0$ we get in Euclidean geometry.